# Text Parsing Tab Delimited file

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a method that reads a file. This file has roughly 30000 lines. However when I read it into an array I get a random length for my array. I have seen it as low 6000.

I used both

`string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\out\qqqqq.txt");`

and

`System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\out\qqqqq.txt");`

(and use a counter.)

But I get the same result. I can see in Excel these are too small.

Comment: Can you open the file in Notepad, go to the end, and see how many lines it tells you are there?

Comment: What's the source of the file? Did you try File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\out\qqqqq.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode) ?

Comment: @Jim excel and notepad are the same.

Comment: @Mark: Yes. Turn on the status line. But you can't display the status line if you have word wrap enabled. Notepad *almost* doesn't suck.

Comment: @JoeTyman: Notepad reports 30,000 lines, but when you do `File.ReadAllLines`, then `lines.Length` is some random number as low as 6,000? That seems ... odd.

Comment: Do a random check to see what's in the first and last element of the `lines` array and check if it's the same as the first and last line of the file.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: Wow, I never knew you could do that! :)

Comment: does your file have the proper end of line markers for each line: 'This method opens a file, reads each line of the file, then adds each line as an element of a string array. It then closes the file. A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a carriage return ('\r'), a line feed ('\n'), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed. The resulting string does not contain the terminating carriage return and/or line feed.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line endings in the file are inconsistent (sometimes `\n`, sometimes `\r\n` and sometimes `\r`) then you could try reading the entire file as a string and splitting it yourself:

```
string file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\out\qqqqq.txt");
var lines = file.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

For large files, this is inefficient, because it needs to read the entire file - using `StreamReader` you would be able to read the file line-by-line as you're processing it. If performance is an issue, then you could write simple tool that first corrects the line endings.

Comment: That will also remove legitimate blank lines.

Comment: @JimMischel - that's true, but if the endings are inconsistent, then it is not clear what is legitimate blank line. For example, is `\r\n` a blank line or no?